# Apex using jquery mobile: Image without rounded corners

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, oracle-apex

I am developing an apex application using jquery mobile. The resulting stripped page looks [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/etrip/cBgQW/).  JQM generates `<span class="ui-btn-inner">`.

How can I influence that behaviour? I want the image appear in a box that has no rounded corners. How can I do that? I am using apex 4.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1 (markup)

Add `data-corners="false"` to your hyperlink. Example:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-corners="false" id="header-menu" title=" ">Click</a>
```

#### Option 2 (CSS)

Open the jQuery mobile CSS file, and search for `.ui-btn-corner-all`. Then remove all `border-radius` elements.